# Underlying mechanics of paired class shares ETFs

Tags: vix, etf

I came across an interesting pair of VIX ETPs, [VXUP and VXDN](http://www.accushares.com/products). This new product referred to as ["paired class shares"](http://www.sec.gov/rules/sro/nasdaq/2015/34-74299.pdf) ETFs are quite different from traditional ETPs. Some interesting highlights from the [prospectus](http://www.accushares.com/resources/vix-fund-prospectus).

> "The Fund will hold only cash, short-dated U.S. Treasuries or
>   collateralized U.S. Treasury repurchases. The Fund will not invest in
>   equity securities, futures, swaps, or other assets that may track its
>   Underlying Index."
>
> "Unlike other exchange traded products, the fund will engage
>   principally in cash distributions and potentially paired share
>   distributions to deliver to the shareholders the economic exposure to
>   the fund’s underlying Index, the CBOE Volatility Index."
>
> "The Fund Will Only Effect Creations and Redemptions in Creation Units
>   Composed of Equal Quantities of Up Shares and Down Shares."

It seems to me it solves some of the problems with other vix ETF/ETNs (credit risk and futures roll contango). However it also seems many more problems are caused, the potential for frequent distributions to eliminate premium/discount can be a tax burden for instance. These distributions will also ensure the up and down shares maintain a certain ratio of aum such that a large movement or redemption in one share class will topple the entire fund.

My question is what are the underlying mechanics that make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [blog post](http://sixfigureinvesting.com/2010/09/how-do-vxup-and-vxdn-work/) that does a great job summarizing the mechanics behind them.

Another great article [on the relationship between the pair and the future.](http://seekingalpha.com/instablog/10211511-eli-mintz/4020976-the-relation-between-vxup-and-the-vix-futures). Which may have an impact on [linearizing the VIX Futures Term Structure?](http://sixfigureinvesting.com/2015/05/vxup-vxdn-impacting-vix-future-term-structure/).

Answer (score 0):

VXUP and VXDN are very new. They have only been in existence for 8 days.

Date    VXUP    VXDN    VIX

5/29/2015   28.47   21.59   13.84

5/28/2015   28.39   21.69   13.31

5/27/2015   28.10   21.65   13.27

5/26/2015   28.91   21.1    14.06

5/22/2015   28.00   21.89   12.13

5/21/2015   28.29   21.86   12.11

5/20/2015   28.51   21.59   12.88

5/19/2015   27.64   22.35   12.85

So far they appear to be doing a poor job of tracking the VIX. For example on May 26 VIX increased by 16% but VXUP only increased by 3.25%.

So in addition to being bafflingly complex (as shown by the prospectus) the structure does not seem to work properly, at least so far.